# Accessing data in vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im trying to access some data I have binded to a component with no luck. How should I do that?

My component:

```
export default {
  name: 'component-vallingby',
  data() {
    return {
  }
},

created() {},

methods: {}
```

}

Here's where im rendering it. Offer is an object:

```
<component-vallingby v-bind="{ offer: offer }"></component-vallingby>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the prop to the component like `:order="order"`. Inside the component vm, list this in `props` array as a `String`.

```
export default {
  name: 'component-vallingby',
  props: ['offer']
}
```

Then instantiate your component passing `order` like this:

```
<component-vallingby :offer="offer"></component-vallingby>
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked. But why would you move the actual data (props, title) outside of the data() ?

Comment: I just deleted them as they seemed empty in your code anyway, just to show that you don't have to list empty properties. `props` is automatically mapped into `data()`.

Comment: Yes, i get that. But why should the props not be a part of the data()? Hence its actually data. (json)

Comment: Well that is how components are designed in Vue.js - go ask Evan You this question :D

Comment: Ok, i will. Let me get back to you!

Comment: Good luck with that! As soon as you have an answer go ask Mark Zuckerberg what he thinks about that

Comment: Ehm, I am Mark Zuckerberg.

Answer (score 1):

You need `props` inside of your `export default {}` mentioned.

```
props: ['offer']
```

You should bind it as

```
<component-vallingby :offer="offer"></component-vallingby>
```